# Accessing JSON within array

Tags: php, json

The following array has JSON within:

```
$row['modifiers']
```

How can I access the `modifier_value` within this?

I have tried:

```
$row['modifiers']['modifier_value'];
```

This is how the array looks:

```
[{"modifier_id":"","modifier_name":"Type","modifier_type":"custom","modifier_value":"Tour","option_id":"","price_mod":"","price_mod_inc_tax":""}]
```

Comment: You'll need to decode that JSON to work with it, otherwise PHP just sees it as a string. Take a look at [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: I already tried decoding but its within 'stdClass Object'. If I decode, how would I access it: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [modifier_id] => [modifier_name] => Type [modifier_type] => custom [modifier_value] => Tour [option_id] => [price_mod] => [price_mod_inc_tax] => ) )

Comment: Niranjan's answer should have you covered but for reference json_decode has a second optional argument that can give you back objects as associative arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
    <?php

    $a = '[{"modifier_id":"","modifier_name":"Type","modifier_type":"custom","modifier_value":"Tour","option_id":"","price_mod":"","price_mod_inc_tax":""}]';

    $decode = json_decode($a);

    foreach ($decode as $arr){
        echo $arr->modifier_name;
        echo $arr->modifier_type;
        // so on
    }

?>
```